# why need typedef in the C++ enum definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I saw the following in the header file

```
typedef enum Test__tag {
    foo,
    bar
} Test;
```

I am wondering why using typedef; I can just use

```
enum Test{
    foo,
    bar
};
```

is that right?

Comment: Using the name `Test__tag` is not a good idea, because all names with double underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Zyx2000 I thought only those which *start* with a double underscore (or single underscore and captial letter).

Comment: @Christian Rau All names with double underscores anywhere are reserved. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier, where the standard is quoted in the first answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's for C users. Basically when you go the `typedef` way, in C you can say

```
Test myTest;
```

whereas when you just used `enum Test`, you'd have to declare a variable like this:

```
enum Test myTest;
```

It's not needed if only C++ is used though. So it might also just be written by a C programmer who is used to this style.

Comment: Or maybe it's a header that's meant to be included by both C and C++ code.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in C++ you declare `x` without the typdef just by writing

```
 enum Test{
    foo,
    bar
};
Test x;
```

However if you were to try the same thing in C you would need to declare `x` as

```
 enum Test x;
```

or use the typedef.

So the the typedef is probably a habit  left over from C (unless the header file is in fact C).